# Flink : How to save list of rows in Database

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Right now I am reading rows from a file and saving in database using the below code:

```
String strQuery = "INSERT INTO public.alarm (id, name, marks) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
JDBCOutputFormat jdbcOutput = JDBCOutputFormat.buildJDBCOutputFormat()
 .setDrivername("org.postgresql.Driver")
 .setDBUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?user=michel&password=polnareff")
 .setQuery(strQuery)
 .setSqlTypes(new int[] { Types.INTEGER, Types.VARCHAR, Types.INTEGER}) //set the types
 .finish();
DataStream<Row> rows = FilterStream
            .map((tuple)-> {
               Row row = new Row(3);                 
               row.setField(0, tuple.f0);            
               row.setField(1, tuple.f1);             
               row.setField(2, tuple.f2);   
               return row;
            });
rows.writeUsingOutputFormat(jdbcOutput);
env.execute();
}
}
```

The above is working fine and it picks rows one by one from a file and saves it in the database.

For example:

If the file contains:

```
1, mark, 20
```

then database entry will look like:

```
id   name   marks
------------------
1    mark   20
```

Now the requirement is for every row, I have to create 2 different rows and it should look like below:

For example:

If the file contains:

```
1, mark, 20
```

then database entry should look like this:

```
id   name   marks
------------------
1    mark-1   20
1    mark-2   20
```

Now I should return List instead of row and datastream variable should look like `DataStream<List<Row>> rows`.

What should I change in JDBCOutputFormat variable in order to achieve this?

Comment: Why not use flatmap to output multiple rows for one input row?

Comment: perfect. Thanks a lot